# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse as array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, error-handling

i have data of set like this:

```
$data[] =
Array
(
    [u_d] => ABCDEF
    [0] => Array
        (
        [one] => oned
        [two] => 222
        [three] => three
        [four] => 444
        [five] => 555
        [events] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [feed] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [date-time] => 191018080000
                                        [sub-type] => abc
                                        [comments] => test comments
                                        [parameter-list] => para1, para2
                                        [state] => bad
                                        [value] => 1000
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [one] => two
            [two] => 224562
            [three] => thyyree
            [four] => 445344
            [five] => 5345355
            [events] => Array
                (
                )

        )
)
```

I need to fetch the event only and remove the empty events. However first i tried to fetch the events liket this, But it give an error.

```
                               $new = [];
                                 for($i=0 ; $i < count($data)-1 ; $i++)
                                {
                                  if(count($data[$i]['events']) > 0)
                                  {
                                    
                                    $new[] = $data[$i]['events'];
                                   
                                  }
                                  
                                }
                                print_r ($new);
```

But it give me an error : Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array

Can anyone please help me to resovle the issue?

Thank you

Comment: `json_decode($data)` First u need to decode json first. After that u can access their value in php way.

Comment: Hi, i tried to decode the json, it give me message":"json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"  ...I also tried to convert from string to array like this $data = array($data); but not working

Comment: Please provide the Full Error Message with Line Number. Also specify the line in your question.

Comment: try like this `$data[$i]->events`

Comment: I tried $data[$i]->events and it igive me error like : Trying to get property of non-object","status_code":

Comment: {"message":"Cannot use object of type Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse as array","status_code":500,"debug":{"line":1400,    It gives me an error on if condition: if(count($data[$i]['events']) > 0)

Comment: This not the code which affect for the issue. Check there should be a place where you try to return a json response and then assign it back to another json response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode **$data[0]** not **$data** since you're doing

```
$data[] =
```

same for loop ,you should do

```
if(count($data[0][$i]['events']) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel collect() method like this:

```
collect($your_array)->toJson();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections

Comment: Hi, I have tried to convert to Json using collect, however, i received a blank Array. Do you know why this happened?